# Получение информации о системе

Tags: метаданные

Пытался выяснить, как спрятать от сайтов информацию о системе. Ответы обычно костыльные типа использовать расширение. Расширения закрывают собой информацию о системе а не меняют ее. Поставлю вопрос по-другому: как, при написании сайта реализовать определение операционной  системы и браузера. Откуда я могу получить эту информацию на уровне кода (JavaScript, html, CSS, php, python)

Comment: Информацию о системе клиента, можно получить анализируя поля http-заголовка. Некоторую дополнительную информацию можно получить используя js. Вопрос достаточно обширный - думаю в интернете можно найти статьи, а вот есть ли "полное собрание".. врядли.

Comment: @nick_n_a а вот http-заголовок откуда конкретно эту информацию берет? наверно это какие-то файлы системы читаются?

Comment: http заголовок делает клиентская программа, чаще всего это Веб-Браузер. Некоторые конкретные браузеры позволяют эту информацию подменить (через about:config). Как браузеры знают - ну например WINAPI. Ну если браузер собрали для винды - то в него зашито что будет винда, и он использует WINAPI, если для линукса - есть API линукса, позволяющее узнать детали системы.